# How to evalutae data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Question:**

How to show on a web page, 100 records at a time (presented in descending order of `id's` from `table1`) and where the `record B` from table1 is not in `table2` add an attribute of "Y" or "N" as I have done in column F of the php_object. Not really sure on the required code and whether this is something I should do in PHP or MySQL and how? Thanks in advance. I would also like to know how to make the result show just one record at a time from table1 that is NOT in table 2 (instead of the most recent 100) - see answer format below.

```
table1                 table2                 php_object1?

  A  |   B  |  C         D  |   B  |  E         A  |   B  |  F     
--------------------   --------------------   -------------------------- 
  X  |   X  |  X         X  |   X  |  X         X  |   X  |  Y
  X  |   X  |  X         X  |   -  |  X         X  |   X  |  N
  X  |   X  |  X         X  |   X  |  X         X  |   X  |  Y
 ...                     ...                   ...
```

**Answer will ultimately be in the following formats**

### Table

Similar to the php_object created above. I want to see ALL the records in table 1 (weather B was present or not). Depending on if B was present make the column Y or N and add conditional formatting to the table1 presented in html (i.e. **highlight the rows in table1 where B is not present in table2**)

### Sentence

"Here is the first `record1` from `table1` where B is not present in `table2`.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT JOIN` on the first case,

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        IF(b.B IS NULL, 'N', 'Y') F
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.B = b.B
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
// LIMIT
```

as for the next problem you want to show 100 records at a time, see pagination

- [PHP Pagination](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html)
- [PHP Pagination](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm)

Comment: Can you please explain the line "IF(b.B IS NULL, 'N', 'Y') F". I don't understand why it is there and why you have 3 values. Can't we just simply do the left join that you suggest? Because table2 will have null value or the data will not equal, this is essentially and anti-join right? Why do we need to row "IF(b.B IS NULL, 'N', 'Y') F" ? thanks

Comment: If you don't do that, you'll get they value of `B` for rows that exist in `b`, and `NULL` for rows that don't exist. You said you wanted `Y` or `N`, and this `IF` expression converts to that format.